# Задачка на массивы

Tags: c

Имеется задача:

> Задан массив `С` из 8 вещественных элементов. Подсчитать в нем количество положительных, отрицательных чисел и нулей.

Насколько я понял, здесь нужно определить 2 переменные (пол. и отр. числа), чтобы вывести их как результат. А сам результат посчитать в цикле for? При этом вроде нужно обнулить счетчик.

Подскажите как будет примерно выглядеть цикл? Вот написал, но чего-то не выводит результат... Подскажите что не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
  int otrec = 0, poloj = 0, zero = 0;
  double A[8], i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    printf("Vvedite element %d\n", i);  
    scanf ("%lf", &A[i]); 
    if (A[i] < 0) otrec++;
    else if (A[i] > 0) poloj++;
    else if (A[i] = 0) zero++;
   }
   printf("otrec=%d\n poloj=%d\n zero=%d\n", otrec, poloj, zero);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: На здоровье !

Comment: Вы массив A[] объявили типа int, а надо double, а otrec, poloj д.б. int, а не float. 

Еще совет - используйте double, а не float - не будет кучи непоняток. float только для экономии памяти (в массивах и если уверены, что не потеряете значащих цифр). А весь ввод-вывод, расчеты, передача параметров - это в double.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!) буду знать, все отлично считает, полож. и отрицательные... Но есть проблема не может посчитать нули?! как записать? задачку исправил в посте)

Comment: else if (A[i] = 0)?!!!!!!!!! Это сравнение или присваивание???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int pol = 0, otr = 0, zero = 0;
int arr = [1, 4, -3, 0, ...];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (arr[i] > 0) pol++;      //Положительное
    else if(arr[i] < 0) otr++;  //Отрицательное
    else zero++;                //Ноль
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (cnt_pos = cnt_neg = cnt_z = i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (C[i] == 0.0)
        cnt_z++;
    else if (C[i] > 0.0) ...
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Вот цикл, для описаной Вами идеи:

```
int otrec = 0;
int poloj = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (mas[i] < 0) otrec++;
    else if (mas[i] > 0) poloj++;
}
```

Comment: А нули кто считать будет?
Хотя очевидно, что если нам известно кол-во элементов `N` и мы посчитали кол-во отрицательных `otrec` и положительных чисел `poloj`, то кол-во нулей `zero` будет равно `zero = N - otrec - poloj`

Comment: сам спросил - сам ответил, у автора это описано в вопросе

Comment: Если автор эту решить не может,не знаю что с ним будет когда начнутся матрицы.Там > или < не обойдешься.

Comment: Це точно...